# Survival probability for individual passenger for Titanic Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

The question is about the famous Titanic dataset from Kaggle. Let's first show the standard procedures to prepare, run algorithms and check the accuracy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Doing a standard cleanup / preparation for the ML algorythms

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\train.csv")

df = df.drop(["Ticket", "Cabin", "PassengerId", "Name"], axis=1)

df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean(), inplace=True)

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Sex', 'Pclass', 'Embarked'], drop_first=True)


# division into train and test

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df.drop("Survived", axis=1)
y = df["Survived"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=42)


# doing StandardScaler manually

df.Age = (df.Age - np.mean(df.Age, axis=0)) / (np.std(df.Age, axis=0))
df.Fare = (df.Fare - np.mean(df.Fare, axis=0)) / (np.std(df.Fare, axis=0))
df.SibSp = (df.SibSp - np.mean(df.SibSp, axis=0)) / (np.std(df.SibSp, axis=0))
df.Parch = (df.Parch - np.mean(df.Parch, axis=0)) / (np.std(df.Parch, axis=0))


# Comparing several algorythms 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression # Logistic Regression
from sklearn import svm  # Support Vector Machine 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier # K Nearest Neighbour
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB # Nayve Bayes
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier # Gradient boosting 

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

algorithms = [LogisticRegression(), svm.SVC(), KNeighborsClassifier(), 
GaussianNB(), GradientBoostingClassifier()]


for algorithm in algorithms:
    clf = algorithm
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    print(f'for {algorithm} the accuracy score is {acc}')
```

So as the result I have the following:

```
for LogisticRegression() the accuracy score is 0.8044692737430168
for SVC() the accuracy score is 0.8156424581005587
for KNeighborsClassifier() the accuracy score is 0.8156424581005587
for GaussianNB() the accuracy score is 0.7653631284916201
for GradientBoostingClassifier() the accuracy score is 0.8212290502793296
```

**My question is:**

is it possible to enrich the code with the following prediction and how?

*"For passenger on index N the survival probability according to LogisticRegression is - 94%, SVC - 67%, KNeighborsClassifier - 83%, GaussianNB - 59%, GradientBoostingClassifier -  66%"* (just inventing the example).

And can I do it on every called passenger?

Comment: Are you asking how to run prediction on data and use in a print statement? Or are you asking how to do batch predictions? I'm not sure the question.

Comment: I want to dig inside the algorithm and find out, when it predicted for a passenger John Dow that it would assign 0 or 1 to it (not survived or survived) what was the probability of  his survival inside the algorithm, at what level the decision was made that '1 should be assigned to this passenger'. Can it be demonstrated as the probability score/percentage?

Comment: I'm still not sure what your asking, but predictions are confidence values, which can be interpreted at probability. That happens with the output layer but you can also access the neurons before that layer and try to figure out how those become your output value.

Answer (score 0):

For most classifiers, you can obtain estimated probabilities via the `predict_proba` method (note that for the [support vector classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) this needs to be explicitly enabled on construction, and the method for estimating probability isn't necessarily robust.)